# I don't understand my code at the last index

Tags: java, arrays

Given an integer array nums and an integer val, remove all occurrences of val in nums in-place. The order of the elements may be changed. Then return the number of elements in nums which are not equal to val.

Consider the number of elements in nums which are not equal to val be k, to get accepted, you need to do the following things:

Change the array nums such that the first k elements of nums contain the elements which are not equal to val. The remaining elements of nums are not important as well as the size of nums.
Return k.

Input: nums = [3,2,2,3], val = 3
Output: 2, nums = [2,2,*,*]

Input: nums = [0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2], val = 2
Output: 5, nums = [0,1,4,0,3,*,*,_]

```
class Solution {
    public int removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {
        int newIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            if (nums[i] != val){
                nums[newIndex] = nums[i];
                newIndex++;

            }
        }
        return newIndex;
    }
}
```

1. With my code, what happens when val is at the last index?
   e.g [1,2,3,4,5,2,2], val = 2;

If "val" is at the last index, wouldn't my code just ignore it and leave it as where it is?

Comment: @Phil when i run with [3,2,2,3] with val = 3, the output array is [2,2]. But I don't know why it wouldn't be [2,2,3] instead.

Answer (score 0):

> If "val" is at the last index, wouldn't my code just ignore it and leave it as where it is?

yes, and that will give a correct answer - acording to the problem text

> when i run with [3,2,2,3] with val = 3, the output array is [2,2]. But I don't know why it wouldn't be [2,2,3] instead.

I tested your code:

http://tpcg.io/_0AFGLH

and it prints:

```
[2, 2, 2, 3]
```

and that is correct, 3 is supposed to be not included in the result. You are supposed to return integer value, lets name it `k`, of number of elements different from val, and that is correct in your code. You are also supposed to modify array so that initial `k` elements are different from val. That is also correct in your code. You dont need to care about the elements `k`+1 in the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

The method returns the number of elements actually in use, the following elements should be be ignored. If you want to avoid reallocating a new array, you may consider passing an additional argument `n` giving the actual length:

```
public int removeElement(int[] nums, int n, int val) {
    int newIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (nums[i] != val){
            nums[newIndex] = nums[i];
            newIndex++;

        }
    }
    return newIndex;
}
```

Otherwise, you can just return a new array:

```
public int[] removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {
    int newIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if (nums[i] != val){
            nums[newIndex] = nums[i];
            newIndex++;

        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, 0, newIndex);
}
```

UPDATE:

Note however that if your array elements were objects instead of `int`s, the first approach could cause memory leaks, unless you were to set to `null` elements at positions from `newIndex` to `n-1`.